# structure with bitfields, memory allocation for array

Tags: c

I want to use a structure as given below on my ARM Cortex M0. I am using C programming.

```
struct path_table_t {
    uint8_t lut_index;
    uint8_t flag : 1;
};
```

`flag` field is made to be single bit by bit fields. How will be the memory allocation for the array of above mentioned structure will happen?

Will I get the benefit of bit fields as saving in total memory?

Comment: Nope. Item memory will be aligned.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the `sizeof(struct path_table_t) == 2`. That is, structure with 2 elements, with each being 8 bits. 7 bits of `flag` should remain unused, but are still reserved.

Note that C standard gives a lot of room for compiler implementation to vary the size required by the bit fields. For example (N1570, 6.7.2.1 p11):

> An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit-
>   field.

and

> The alignment of the addressable storage unit is unspecified.

So the space being reserved by the `flag` and its padding might be even larger.

If you wish to be sure, check the size with `sizeof`. Just remember that changing compiler or compiler settings might affect the result.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question
 `Will I get the benefit of bit fields as saving in total memory?` 
`NO`

consider two struct's

```
struct path_table1_t {
    uint8_t lut_index;
    uint8_t flag : 1;
}a;
```

and

```
struct path_table2_t {
    uint8_t lut_index;
    uint8_t flag;
}b;
```

`sizeof(a)` and `sizeof(b)` is **equal**.

But incase you are planning to use all the bits in the given bit field then the memory allocated is reduced. Like

```
struct path_table3_t {
    uint8_t lut_index : 1;
    uint8_t flag : 1;
}c;
```

In this case the sizeof(c) is the sizeof(uint8_t) which will be 1 byte.
To summarize: 
`sizeof(c) < sizeof(a)` and `sizeof(a) = sizeof(b)`

If you are very much interested to save memory then use the keyword `__attribute__((__packed__))` , where this directive would make compiler to squeeze in the memory allocated for this struct upto which the user is using.

Answer (score 0):

Memory allocation for bit fields is implementation defined.
Let's consider your example:

```
struct path_table_t {
   uint8_t lut_index;
   uint8_t flag : 1;
};

int main()
{
   struct path_table_t p;

   printf("%d\n",sizeof(p));
}
```

Here you want totally 9 bits of usage so it will be padded to 2 bytes.

If your structure was like

```
struct path_table_t {
   uint8_t lut_index : 1;
   uint8_t flag : 1;
};

int main()
{
   struct path_table_t p;

   printf("%d\n",sizeof(p));
}
```

You see here only 2 bits is required so your `sizeof(struct)` would be 1 byte which answers your question.
Yes using bit fields can save memory as shown above.